# Quotation marks and commas

Tags: commas, writing-style, quotations, quotation-marks

I know that, when using a period, comma, or exclamation mark with quotation marks, we should generally place the punctuation inside the quotes. Does this hold in general?

For example, consider the quote

```
However, when he said "the bag is open", he meant that the bag was not closed.
```

Should the comma be placed within the quotation marks, as follows

```
However, when he said "the bag is open," he meant that the bag was not closed.
```

Is this different between American and British English?

Comment: To a large extent it depends on who's style guide you are reading and the conventions of BrE versus AmE.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the pair of commas are used in place of parenthesis

```
However (when he said "the bag is open") he meant that the bag was not closed.
```

so the second comma is not part of the quote and should be outside the quotation marks.

Having now read Kate Bunting's comment, I think the third answer (WBT's score 5) to the that question sums it up best.